# How to debug/log preprocessor macros in Xcode (iOS)?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, logging

The question is stated in title, the main purpose is to be able to efficiently debug some runtime-version-specific or scheme-specific code.

So for example, is it possible to log the value of `DEBUG` in xcode's console?

EDIT:

I should rephrase the question, I understand we can use `NSLog("DEBUG = %d", DEBUG);` to log a macro's value (thx @rmaddy), the question should be:

Is there better way? eg. not needing to add a command and recompile just to get the value of a single macro

Comment: This seems too obvious: `NSLog("DEBUG = %d", DEBUG);`.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for your fast response. sadly, i can't get your command to compile (using Xcode 6 + iOS SDK 8.1). And more importantly, it would be more desirable not needing to add a command and compile again to log every macro.

Comment: Why won't it compile? What's the error?

Comment: oh, got the reason, it should be `NSLog(@"DEBUG = %d", DEBUG);` :)

Comment: Oops - I forgot the `@` when I typed it in.

Comment: haha, there's gotcha like this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems a little confusing because of the mention of "runtime-version-specific". Preprocessor macros are compile-time settings rather than runtime settings.

If all you need is to find the iOS **predefined** macros for Xcode 6, type this into the terminal:

```
llvm-gcc -arch armv7 -dM -E – < /dev/null | sort
```

(Yes, there is a single dash by itself.)
Change the -arch option to “armv6″ or “armv7″ or “armv7s” as needed.

This can probably be extended to preprocess your project's code and show all the preprocessor macros. But that will be a compile-time operation rather than run-time.

To print the values of your custom macros at runtime would require specifically writing at least some code for each macro. Macros are tricky things.  They may be #defined to one value or another or not #defined at all.  They might also be #defined as numbers, or #defined as text, or object literals such as NSString, NSDictionary or NSNumber or any kind of object pointer.

The C standard "[stringification operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)" ('#') may be of interest if you really need to print things out at run-time.